# Smart card application using Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, smartcard

I want to know how a smart card application can be done using Java EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a smart card application? If you're talking about Java smart cards and applications, you probably mean JavaCard, which is not related to Java EE. If you're talkig about some kind of "enterprise application" that uses smart cards for some purpose, like authentication or digital signatures, you need to be more specific about your use cases.

Comment: Hai martin iam developing an attendance management system in my office.. Users will be given an access card when they swipe it they ll be marked as present for the day....

Comment: Well, in that case you need a client side component that would actually interact with the reader and card (be it contactless or not)

Answer (score 1):

There are also a couple of solutions for integrating smart cards with web sites using a browser plug-in instead of other client side solutions. Gemalto makes a product called "Sconnect" (www.sconnect.com) and my company(Comet Way) makes "Card Boss" (https://cardboss.cometway.com), I'm not sure about the Gemalto product but Card Boss will work with any kind of web browser or server platform (Java EE, asp.net, plain HTML).